# How can I change the number of rows to display in ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid to generate data tables. At the beginning I created a file.js which was static, in this file I had a code which worked for me to choose if I wanted to show only 15 rows, 25 rows or 100 rows.

The above worked well, but I changed the method to generate my table and data dynamically. I used fetch to generate the table by obtaining the data through a json path. So far it works and shows me the data correctly. The problem is that now I can't choose whether I want to select 15 rows to display, or 25 rows or 100 rows.

```
// Fetch the data, then setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // Querying the data using fetch and promises
  fetch('/data.evento')
    // Deserializing the data we received
    .then(response => response.json())
    // We have our data now, we initialize our table
    .then(data => {
      const gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
      new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, {
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        defaultColDef: {
          flex: 1,
          minWidth: 150,
          resizable: true,
          enableValue: true,
          enableRowGroup: true,
          enablePivot: true,
          sortable: true,
          filter: true,
          filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
          menuTabs: ['filterMenuTab', 'generalMenuTab', 'columnsMenuTab'],
        },
        suppressRowClickSelection: true,
        rowSelection: 'multiple',
        enableRangeSelection: true,
        autoGroupColumnDef: {
          minWidth: 200,
        },
        sideBar: ['columns', 'filters'],
        animateRows: true,
        pagination: true,
        paginationPageSize: 15,
        domLayout: 'autoHeight',
        enableSorting: true,
        enableFilter: true,
        rowData: data
      });
});
```

Through the previous code I generate my table with the data, and the following code served me to select the number of rows to display in my table.

```
var changePageSizeFunction;

changePageSizeFunction = function () {
  const pageSizeSelect = document.getElementById('pageSizeSelect');
  const selectedPageSize = parseInt(pageSizeSelect.value, 10);

  if (selectedPageSize === -1) {
    // Si se selecciona "Todos", establecer un tamaño de página alto para mostrar todos los elementos.
    gridOptions.api.paginationSetPageSize(Number.MAX_VALUE);
  } else {
    gridOptions.api.paginationSetPageSize(selectedPageSize);
  }
};
```

The problem is that before all the code of options of the table was saved in the gridOptions variable and now with the change, all the gridOptions variables I have declared without the gridOptions variable. Then I don't know how to call this configuration variable:

```
gridOptions.api.paginationSetPageSize(selectedpageSize);
```

On my front-end side I have this:

```
<label for="pageSizeSelect">Mostrar:</label>
<select id="pageSizeSelect" onchange="changePageSizeFunction()">
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
<option value="-1">Todos</option>
</select>
```

I would like to know how I can make my code work or if there is any other way to select the number of rows to display within my table, it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you define a variable outside of your DOMContentLoaded event and assign your grid options into it?

```
let gridOptions;
// Fetch the data, then setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // Querying the data using fetch and promises
  fetch('/data.evento')
    // Deserializing the data we received
    .then(response => response.json())
    // We have our data now, we initialize our table
    .then(data => {
      const gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');

      // assignment here
      gridOptions =         
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        defaultColDef: {
          flex: 1,
          minWidth: 150,
          resizable: true,
          enableValue: true,
          enableRowGroup: true,
          enablePivot: true,
          sortable: true,
          filter: true,
          filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
          menuTabs: ['filterMenuTab', 'generalMenuTab', 'columnsMenuTab'],
        },
        suppressRowClickSelection: true,
        rowSelection: 'multiple',
        enableRangeSelection: true,
        autoGroupColumnDef: {
          minWidth: 200,
        },
        sideBar: ['columns', 'filters'],
        animateRows: true,
        pagination: true,
        paginationPageSize: 15,
        domLayout: 'autoHeight',
        enableSorting: true,
        enableFilter: true,
        rowData: data
      };

      new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
});
```

You can check this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/PDQhsuJ7jTAVc5Dd?preview